# Is there an easy way to get all info from a excel user form?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Im trying to fill a excel "database" with new products.

My manager is looking for a better database, instead of excel, but for the time being im stuck with excel.
So instead of filling every cell manually with the details of said item, is there a way i can do it quicker?

How i would do it with my limited knowledge is:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

    'variable to store the count of rows.
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim iRowCode As Long

    'get the count cells that are filled
    irow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Bron calculatie").Range("D:D"))

    'get to the next blank cell in column G
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, 7).Value = ADD_ITEM.ART.Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, 8).Value = ADD_ITEM.BREED.Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, 9).Value = ADD_ITEM.DIEP.Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, 10).Value = ADD_ITEM.ZITH.Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, 11).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, 12).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, 13).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow + 1, ).Value = ADD_ITEM..Value


    MsgBox Chr(10) & "Artikel is toegevoegd" & Chr(10)
    
    Unload Me
    End

End Sub
```

So there is a form with multiple tabs where i can fill certain costs and hours work etc and it will automaticly fill in a new row with the new product. The thing is that there are about 350 cells to fill. Some items need 10 of those others need 40 but all 350 are different and needed. Is this still the "best" way or is there a quicker/ easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read each TextBox (Control) name and value using the following loop:

```
Sub read_userform_textboxes()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    
    For Each ctrl In ADD_ITEM.Controls
    
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
    
            Debug.Print ctrl.Name, ctrl.Text
    
        End If
        
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CLR for giving me the idea for this.
If you give your textboxes similar names to the headers in your sheet, even with that many, the loop is gonna be far shorter. The setup of your textboxes is quite long, I'll admit but afterwards, it shouldn't be so much a hassle anymore. For the textboxes I used "txtBoxArt" for Art as the header of the column you'd want that in and so on.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
        'variable to store the count of rows.
    Dim irow As Long, ws As Worksheet, lCol As Long
    Dim arrHeaders
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bron Calculatie")
    With ws
        irow = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'max Columns
        arrHeaders = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol)).Value
        With Application
            arrHeaders = .Transpose(.Transpose(.Index(arrHeaders, 1, 0))) 'getting it into a 1D-array
        End With
    End With
    Dim arrPrint '1 row in your datasheet
    ReDim arrPrint(1 To lCol)
    Dim pos As Long
        
    'Thanks to CLR for the looping through the controls which gave me this idea
    Dim ctrl As Control
    
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            'find the position of the header-column corresponding to the txtBox name
            pos = Application.Match(Right(ctrl.Name, Len(ctrl.Name) - 6), arrHeaders, False)
            arrPrint(pos) = ctrl.Text
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("A" & irow + 1).Resize(, lCol).Value = arrPrint
End Sub
```

I stepped away from the 350 in case there were more in between that you weren't filling from the userform.
Let me know if I missed something :)

Comment: ...or add a line above your column headers which has the name of the control to source the value from.

Comment: Could do that as well, yeah if the user doesn't mind it.